# Qt Connect to std::function

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to define the SIGNAL for a connection at run time, as it depends upon which derived class has created the object in question. I.e. I'm defining a base class that has an abstract slot (that the derived classes implement accordingly). Then, at the point of object construction I pass a `std::function<void(uint)>` to the base class' constructor using `std::bind(&Class::signalToPass, object, std::placeholder::_1)`. I'm then trying to use `QObject::connect` to connect this `std::function` to the aforementioned abstract slot. I'll try and outline an example below:

The derived classes constructor:

```
DerviedClass(SomeClass *someObject) : BaseClass(std::bind(&SomeClass::methodToConnect, someObject, std::placeholders_1)
{
    ...
}
```

The base classes constructor:

```
BaseClass(std::function<void(uint)> methodToConnect) m_methodToConnect(methodToConnect)
{
    createConnections();
}
void BaseClass::createConnections()
{
    QObject::connect(
        this,
        m_methodToConnect,
        this,
        &BaseClass::abstractSlot);

    ...
}
```

Where `m_methodToConnect` is defined as a private `std::function<void(uint)>` within `BaseClass`.

I can get this to compile one of two ways, which both lead to runtime errors...
1st:

```
QObject::connect(
    this,
    SIGNAL(m_methodToConnect),
    this,
    SLOT(abstractSlot));
```

This results in the runtime warning:

```
QObject::connect: Parentheses expected, signal DerivedClass::m_methodToConnect in /home/...
```

Which I thought I understood so altered to this:

```
QObject::connect(
    this,
    SIGNAL(m_methodToConnect(uint)),
    this,
    SLOT(abstractSlot(uint)));
```

This results in the runtime warning:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal DerivedClass::m_methodToConnect(uint) in /home/...
```

I have also tried to pass `someObject` from the derived class to the base class and used that as the "sender" in `QObject::connect`, but the same result is seen. In all cases I can compile, build and install on my target, but as expected the connection isn't made.

Any help on this would be appreciated, also, as an FYI (and probably evident from the post) my knowledge of Qt's signal/slot handling is far from perfect...

Comment: You can't do this with the old Qt4 SIGNAL() and SLOT() syntax at least directly.

Comment: FYI: [New Signal Slot Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)

Comment: It is able to compile because SIGNAL just converts `m_methodToConnect` to a string. It doesn't find out until runtime that the string is not the name of a defined signal.

Comment: I never tried to connect a `std::function` directly as slot (and already am too tired to think whether/how it might work). If it doesn't work directly you still can wrap it into a lambda (used as adapter). [Advanced Signals and Slots Usage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#advanced-signals-and-slots-usage)

Comment: Folks, note that the OP is trying to use the `std::function<void(uint)>` `m_methodToConnect` as a *signal*, not a slot.  I think there's some confusion as to the purpose/usage of the signal/slot mechanism.  Perhaps the OP could clarify exactly what they're trying to achieve.

Comment: Okay, the ``SIGNAL`` macro simply converting to a string makes sense as to why it suddenly compiles... The rest of my application uses the new Signal Slot mechanism, but in this case I get conversion conflicts trying to convert from ‘std::function<void(unsigned int)>’ to ‘const QMetaMethod&’

Comment: @G.M. What I'm trying to do is move the ``createConnections()`` method out of each derived class and into the base class, as they always connect to the same Slot, but each derived class connects a different Signal to said Slot. Therefore, the simplest way I could think to do this, was to pass a std::function to the constructor of the base class, and connect to this...

Comment: You can use the Qt4 syntax and pass `const char*` for the signal.

Comment: I've read your last comment: _as they always connect to the same Slot, but each derived class connects a different Signal to said Slot._ You could provide a `virtual` method which returns the signal to connect and is overridden in the derived classes. However, in this case the connection cannot be done in the base class constructor as virtual methods don't work in constructors.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, but given there's not a way to do this as elegantly as I had hoped, I have simply decided to override the ``createConnections()`` method in each derived class instead.

Answer (score 3):

I'm too tired to think this through but not too tired to try this out.

I was pessimating…

`std::function` objects can be used like any function or functor. It's essential that it provides a matching signature – that's all.

Demonstration:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QPushButton qBtn("Click me");
  qBtn.show();
  // install signal handlers
  std::function<void(bool)> func = [](bool) { qDebug() << "Button clicked."; };
  QObject::connect(&qBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, func);
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image: Snapshot of testQSignalStdFunction]

Of course, it is necessary to make the signal/slot connections in Qt5 style.

In Qt4, signal/slot connections were done using the QMeta things which required explicit remark of slots. In this case, I wouldn't bet on `std::function` but there is still the option to wrap its call into a member function which is declared as slot like usual in Qt4.

Comment: Thanks for the demonstration, that seems to work nicely when the std::function is the Slot, but I was hoping to have it be the Signal (at that's what's dependant on which derived class calls my base class' constructor). Do you know if this functionality is possible (a "normal" slot, and a std::function acting as the Signal)?

Comment: `std::function` is a storage for functions and functors. A signal is a container to store functions and functors. So, `std::function` cannot be a Qt signal. You may build something like a signal from a `std::vector` which stores `std::function`s and "emit" it by iterating over the vector and calling each stored `std::function` element but that's not quite the same like a Qt signal. (A Qt signal provides a bit more beyond this.)